# fsx script finishes before async response is back

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have the following .fsx script:

```
#r "packages/FSharp.Data/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

async { let! html = Http.AsyncRequestString("http://stackoverflow.com")
        printfn "%d" html.Length }
|> Async.Start
```

The code is correct, since it works as expected in `fsharpi`. I suspect what's happening is that the script exits before the async response is back. What's the easiest way to wait for the response to be back?

Comment: ? |> Async.RunSynchronously

Comment: To expand on @s952163's comment, Async.Start will start the async task, but not wait for it.  In `fsharpi` the task finishes because `fsharpi` stays alive after the current command is finished running.  When you execute a script, the process ends as soon as the main thread finishes (kiiind of, you can tell certain types of threads to keep the process open), which this one does as soon as the async process is started (since Async.Start doesn't wait).  Using Async.RunSynchronously tells F# to not just start the async call, but also block until it finishes.

Comment: @infinitypanda thanks for the additional comments! GiantSquid, I'm posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `|> Async.RunSynchronously` in this case. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx or Chapter 11 in the Expert F# 4.0 book. `Async.Start` can be very useful kicking of functions that will return their results to the GUI without blocking.